# HTTP request in Docker container fails with HTTPS endpoint

Tags: rest, docker, go, https

I have build a small app in golang, using the alpine:golang base image that amongst other things consumes a response from HTTP.get.

The api endpoint I am requesting is operating over HTTPS (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)

The code works fine locally, and the docker image builds fine, but when run I get the following error:

```
The HTTP request failed with error Get "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I'm not sure if this is a specific Docker issue (I can't curl HTTPS from other docker containers), a limitation of my network (I'm not on VPN but we do use zScaler), or whether I need to include/configure something as part of my Dockerfile. My dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine:golang

#Create and set the working directory
RUN mkdir /app 
WORKDIR /app 

# Copy all the go scripts into the image working directory
COPY /pipelines/core/rtbf-pipeline-1 ./


# Make the binaries executable
RUN chmod +x /app/rtbf-pipeline-1

CMD ["app"]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to copy over a set of trusted root certificates to your Docker image.

In your `Dockerfile` add something like:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build

// build your go app here

FROM scratch

// copy go app from `build`
// ...

//
// add trust certs
//
COPY --from=build etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not 100% sure where to find the ca-certificates.crt? Is that something I should generate myself using openssl or something?

Comment: the file is in `golang:alpine` image: `docker run -it golang:alpine ls -al /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`  `-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        232933 Apr 24 14:29 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: So the above (two stage)`Dockerfile` will simply copy it from the docker `build` image to your destination `scratch` image.

Comment: I'm basing my go app in the golang:alpine image though, I'm not using scratch. So if it's already there why isn't it validating it?

Comment: Could this be because of intermediate cert issues? My laptop has zscaler installed as its a company device?

Comment: is your `golang:alpine` image up-to-date? `docker image ls golang` my `golang:alpine` is from 2 weeks ago - how old is yours? The `/etc/ssl` should be able to recognize this website.

Comment: Are you using custom TLS configs? or Transports?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add

```yaml
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```